# Last Year value with current Parameters Start and End Date

Tags: reporting-services

I'm trying to get last year values output with current year 
i set two parameters and which showing me start date and End date i need to know what was the vakluse last year i

```
=count(IIF(Fields!BookingDate.Value = DATEADD("yyyy",-1,Parameters!StartDate.Value) & Fields!BookingDate.Value = DATEADD("yyyy",-1,Parameters!EndDate.Value)
,Fields!Base.Value, Nothing),"Hotel_Booking")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
=COUNT(
  IIF(
      Fields!BookingDate.Value >= DATEADD(DateInterval.Year,-1,Parameters!StartDate.Value) AND
      Fields!BookingDate.Value <= DATEADD(DateInterval.Year,-1,Parameters!EndDate.Value),
      Fields!Base.Value, Nothing
  ))
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Nope getting 
DateInverval i snot declared. it may be inaccessible due to its protection level

Comment: well i used the DateInterval.Year and still not getting Answer

Comment: @Skorpion, could you add a sample dataset and explain your expected result?